# Can't get modf() to work

Tags: c, xcode4

Can't get the modf() to work.

Have included Xcode compiler error messages following comments.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double pi = 3.14;                           // Unused variable
    double integerPart;                         // Unused variable
    double fractionPart;                        // Unused variable
}

// Pass the address of integerPart as an argument
fractionPart = modf(pi, &integerPart);          /* Use of undeclared identifier      'integerPart'; did you mean integer_t? */

// Find the value stored in integer part
printf("integerPart = %.0f, fractionPart = %.2f\n", integerPart, fractionPart);     //   Expected ')'

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Remove the '}' from the middle of your main function.

Comment: @GuySirton: That should be an answer.

Comment: You don't need to include stdio.h or math.h, Foundation.h already includes them. Or more precisely, Foundation.h includes CoreFoundation.h which includes all standard C headers (take a look in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes but so trivial I felt it doesn't deserve that high status :-)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the '}' from the middle of your main function.